# SQL Server : how to fill columns with variable data, temp table?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Here is the basic query, the question marks are where I need some help (at the least)

```
Declare @Start datetime
Declare @End datetime

Set @Start = {mindate}
Set @End = {maxdate}

Select    
    e.id, p.date, p.pdn1?, p.hours1?, p.pdn2?, p.hours2? ... p.pdn10?, p.hours10?
from 
    e
join 
    p on e.filekey = p.filekey
where 
    p.eventdate between @start and @end
```

Table e

```
uniqueid
filekey
id
```

table p

```
uniqueid
filekey
eventdate
pdn
hours
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
id     date     cat1     hours1     cat2    hours2   ....   cat10     hours10
```

The issue I'm having is that there are 39 different pdn's and up to 10 of them may be present on a specific date.  if the p.hours associated with that p.pdn is 0 or not present, it shouldn't be present in the final result.  the p table contains the data on different lines but I need to combine the different lines onto the same row if the p.eventdate is the same.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: By not present in the final result you mean `NULL`, or the column is not included at all? Or do you want one output with concatenated values in a single column that excludes the `NULL` values?

Comment: I mean that the p.hours associated with that particular p.pdn would not be present and either the columns would be filled with a different p.pdn with corresponding hours that are not 0 or if there are no additional p.pdn's with corresponding hours > 0 then those fields will be NULL

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it, although you might want to use RANK() or something depending on how the hours are done or if pdn needs to be ordered.[Rextester example](http://rextester.com/OAIDVA49863)

```
declare @Start datetime
declare @End datetime

set @Start = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
set @End = CAST(DATEADD(day,1,GETDATE()) as DATE)

;WITH CTE AS
(
    select uniqueid, pdn, hours, filekey, eventdate,
           'PDN' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY filekey ORDER BY hours) as varchar) as PDNrnk,
           'HOURS' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY filekey ORDER BY hours) as varchar) as Hoursrnk
    from p
    where hours > 0
          and eventdate >= @start and eventdate < @end
)
select  id, eventdate as date, 
        MAX([PDN1]) as CAT1,MAX([HOURS1]) as HOURS1,
        MAX([PDN2]) as CAT2,MAX([HOURS2]) as HOURS2,
        MAX([PDN3]) as CAT3,MAX([HOURS3]) as HOURS3,
        MAX([PDN4]) as CAT4,MAX([HOURS4]) as HOURS4,
        MAX([PDN5]) as CAT5,MAX([HOURS5]) as HOURS5,
        MAX([PDN6]) as CAT6,MAX([HOURS6]) as HOURS6,
        MAX([PDN7]) as CAT7,MAX([HOURS7]) as HOURS7,
        MAX([PDN8]) as CAT8,MAX([HOURS8]) as HOURS8,
        MAX([PDN9]) as CAT9,MAX([HOURS9]) as HOURS9,
        MAX([PDN10]) as CAT10,MAX([HOURS10]) as HOURS10
from 
(
    select e.id,cte.eventdate,cte.pdn,cte.Hours,cte.PDNrnk, cte.Hoursrnk
    from e
    inner join CTE
        on (e.filekey = CTE.filekey)
)q
PIVOT 
(
    MIN(Pdn)
    FOR PDNrnk in ([PDN1],[PDN2],[PDN3],[PDN4],[PDN5],[PDN6],[PDN7],[PDN8],[PDN9],[PDN10])
)as pvtPdn
PIVOT 
(
    MIN(Hours)
    FOR Hoursrnk in ([HOURS1],[HOURS2],[HOURS3],[HOURS4],[HOURS5],[HOURS6],[HOURS7],[HOURS8],[HOURS9],[HOURS10])
)as pvtHours
group by id, eventdate
```